# Display Current date in DatePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I wanna display a **Time Picker** in my android app but when time picker displays it display current minute and hour but it can't set that it is *AM* or *PM*.

Snapshot of the code sample used to populate time Picker

```
return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener,
c.get(Calendar.HOUR), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
```

[image: Sample of timepicker]

In the above image snap of time picker which display irrespective of the current *AM* or *PM*. I want in time picker it should display that whether it is *AM* or *PM*.

Comment: I guess you need to set it dynamically.

Comment: you can use c.get(Calendar.AM_PM)

Comment: @GokhanArik dude can you explain how to set it dynamically ???

Comment: Try this `yourpicker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));` In your case it would be just `c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY
```

Instead of

```
Calendar.HOUR
```